# node.js Check if payload header contains predefined sequence of characters, protocol - TLS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, payload

I need to check, does paket payload header contains some defined data sequence. let's say somethng like "0xABCDEF65432ZZZ". Could you please give me some tips, how to do that.

UPD: Protocol is TLS 1.2

Comment: Is this a question about how to process strings, or is it about how to extract the payload from an HTTP request?

Comment: What protocol is this? HTTP? UDP? A custom TCP protocol? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The request: curl localhost:8080/url --data "{\"key\": \"keyValue\"}" --header "content-type:application/json"

It depends.. if you wanna do it with http only:

```
var http = require('http');

function listener(req, res){
    switch(req.method){
        case 'POST':
            req.on('data', function(d){
                var data = JSON.parse(d.toString())
                console.log('data ', data.key); // output: data keyValue
                    res.end('processed...');
            });
    }
}

var server = http.createServer(listener);
server.listen(8080);
console.log('server started..');
```

As you can see, if you are going to develop something, is better to use a framework, I suggest [express](http://expressjs.com/):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.post('/url', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.key); //outputs: keyValue
    res.end('processed...');
});
server.listen(8080);
console.log('server started..');
```

Edit:

If you are using tls native module...

```
tls.createServer(options, function (socket) {
    socket.addListener("data", function (data) {
         //use the data as you want..
    });
   socket.pipe(socket);
}).listen(8000);
```

take a look to this [document](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/07/04/tlsssl-tunneling-with-nodejs/), is kind of old. But could be some help.

at the end, if you want to use a library to encapsulate this kind of works for you..
[this](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#tls) seems to be a good choice...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're probably trying to get the payload header from a TCP packet.

You should look into the [raw-socket](https://www.npmjs.org/package/raw-socket) module.